# Looking for a tool to create a complex windows installer package

Tags: installation, windows-installer

Part of our business includes providing a (windows) desktop machine with a pile of Data Acquisition Cards and associated software all set up and working for our customers.

Right now, we package up all our software, dependencies, drivers, etc and a pile of bat scripts, and this is our "install tool". Our production staff run the scripts (in order), choosing options as required and they eventually get the machine configured and tested.

The process isn't great - it's a bit buggy and really should just be a lot easier.

It's occurred to me that there must be an installer technology out there that we can use to replace our bat scripting. Does anyone know of something we could use?

It should:

- Be able to install multiple pieces of software (ie run *their* installers with all default options on).
- Be able to have some scripting/customization ability, because we'd want to be able to recreate some of the things our .bat scripts do.
- Preferably provide some UI - ie click through installations screens with options.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13495092/1035521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we have gone with Wix - Installshield looked great - but... in the end it was just calling a whole pile of custom build scripts.

Wix has a high learning curve, but is more like what we need.

Answer (score 0):

There are many installers tools, and different people prefer different tools. You won't find the best one, because some tools fit for one tasks more than others, some expensive, some really bad and expensive and so on. 
But in your case, I can recommend use Windows Installer technology and InstallShield tool for it, base on my experience. It has a lot of possibilities to create great and powerful installers. With help of Windows Installer and own InstallShield features. 
Also all your requirements could be done with InstallShield.